# Sending a generated token for email verification after registration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having hard time getting it right with the php script.

Basically, I want the users who register on my site to verify their email before they continue after registration. It appears that after registration, data and generated token stored in database successfullly but the email sent to the user does not include the token generated and i don't know what am not doing right even with the sendEmail functions which crashes the site.

Here are code snippet; for register.php, class.user.php, email_verify.php, verify.php.

**register.php**

```
//Php Validation
    if($firstName == "")    {
        $error[] = "Your First Name is required!";  
    }
    if($lastName == "") {
        $error[] = "Your Last Name is required!";   
    }
    else if($email == "")   {
        $error[] = "Your Email Address is required!";   
    }
    else if($phone == "")   {
        $error[] = "Your Phone Number is required!";    
    }
    else if(strlen($phone) < 10 || strlen($phone) > 15){
        $error[] = "Please enter a valid Mobile Number!";   
    }
    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address !';
    }
    else if($confirmEmail == "")    {
        $error[] = "Please confirm your email address !";
    }
    else if($confirmEmail != $email)    {
        $error[] = "Email Address does not match, please check and re-enter!";
    }
    else if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $error[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters"; 
    }
    else if($passwordConfirm != $password)  {
        $error[] = "Password does not match, please try again!";
    }       
    else if($country == "") {
        $error[] = "Please select your Country!";
    }
    else{
        try {
            $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users 
                WHERE email=:email OR phone=:phone");
            $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email, ':phone'=>$phone));
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            //Check if referral or sponsor exist
            $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT email FROM users 
                WHERE email=:referral");
            $stmt->execute(array(':referral'=>$referral));
            $ref = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($row['email'] == $email) {
                $error[] = "Sorry, Email Address already in use in the system!";
            }elseif($row['phone'] == $phone) {
                $error[] = "Sorry, Phone Number already in use in the system!";
            }elseif(!isset($ref['email']) OR $ref['email'] == ""){
                $error[] = "Opps! Sponsor doesn't exist in the system. Please use oshebase@gmail.com for test sponsore!";
            }
            else{
                if($auth_user->register($firstName, $firstName, $email, $password, $referral, $country, $phone)){
                    $auth_user->redirect(BASE_URL.'verification?link-sent');
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

**class.user.php;**
i commented out the sendEmail function which usually crash the site.

```
//Registration Function
    public function register($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, $referral, $country, $phone){
        try {
            $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50)); // generate unique token
            $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);     
            $stmt = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users(email, password, first_name, last_name, referral, country, token, status, signup_date, last_login, last_updated, email_verify, phone) 

            VALUES(:email, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :referral, :country, :token, 'Active', now(), now(), now(), '0', :phone)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":firstName", $firstName);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lastName", $lastName);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":password", $new_password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":referral", $referral);
            $stmt->bindparam(":country", $country); 
            $stmt->bindparam(":phone", $phone);
            $stmt->bindparam(":token", $token);
            $stmt->execute();
            $loginID = $this->connect->lastInsertId();

            //include welcome Email File
            $results = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM website_settings 
                WHERE id='1'");
            $results->execute();
            $siteInfo = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            include(ROOT_PATH."emailTemplates/welcomeMsg.php");

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)  {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }

    /*public function sendEmail($email, $token){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT login_id, email, token FROM users 
                WHERE email=:email AND email_verify='0'");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $email);
            $stmt->bindParam(":token", $token);
            $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$userID));

            include(ROOT_PATH."emailTemplates/email_verify.php");

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)  {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }*/
```

**email_verify.php**

```
<?php
$emailBody = "";
$emailBody = $emailBody ."Hello  " . $username . ",\n<br />";
$emailBody = $emailBody .'Thanks so much for joining us. <br><br>To get started <a href="https://www.sitename.com/verification?email='.$email.'&token='.$token.'">Verify your account</a><br><br> OR copy and past the following code on your browser:<br>https://www.sitename.com/verification?email='.$email.'&token='.$token.' <br><br>to continue.<br><br>Thanks for signing up into the system. <br />';

// Sending mail
$to = "$email"; 
$from = "Site name <noreply@sitename.com>"; 
$subject = 'Verify Your Email Address'; 
//$message = ""; 
$headers = "From: $from\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers);
?>
```

**verify.php**

```
//Grab email and token from the verification link and checks if exist in the system
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['token'])){
    $userID = intval($_GET['true']);
    try {
        $stmt = $login->runQuery("UPDATE users SET email_verify='1' WHERE email=:email AND token=:token");
        $stmt->execute(array(":userID"=>$userID));  
        $login->redirect(BASE_URL.'verification?verified');
        exit();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope there will be more than `....which usually crash the site.`   Is there any logging? Did you try to enable logging?  What is in this logging? (probably a hint to solve this problem.... )

Comment: Thank you @Luuk, i realised i did not call the sendEmail function on register.php which i did with;   `elseif($auth_user->sendEmail($email, $token)){
           $auth_user->redirect(BASE_URL.'verification?link-sent');
           exit();
              }
              else{
               $error = "Oops! There is a problem sending email verification. please try again!";
              }`     which i added next after the else statement that transfer the form data. Which then solved the issue of the site crashing and now the register.php crashes upon form submission and return upon reload.